# Diz-se “valva” ou “válvula”?

Tags: diferenças, diferenças-transatlânticas, termos

Na escola, aprendi que o coração tem quatro **válvulas**; quando fui ao médico, ouvi de uma **válvula** defeituosa; e, quando pesquiso na Internet, vejo **válvula**. Mas já ouvi se dizendo que *valva* é mais usada, pelo menos para algumas das válvulas. Isto me deixou confuso, inclusive porque ouvi que, em Portugal, diz-se diferente.

Afinal, usa-se «válvula» ou «valva»? E, se são, de alguma sorte, diferentes, qual a diferença? se não for uma pergunta técnica demais.

Comment: FWIW, posso imaginar que seja uma pronúncia possível (assim como, e.g., "varva"), mas não me lembro de ter escutado "valva" e nunca vi escrito antes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Etimologicamente, *válvula* é diminutivo de *valva*. No [latim, *valva*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/valva#Latin) era a porta de duas metades, que abrem uma para cada lado.

No português, tradicionalmente, ***valva*** significou apenas, e continua a significar, a concha dos moluscos, incluindo as dos bivalves, que têm duas valvas ([Moraes Silva 1789](https://books.google.pt/books?id=rwVdAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA508&lpg=PA508&dq=%22pe%C3%A7a%20d%20que%20consta%22&source=bl&ots=UHDF-pb5mM&sig=ACfU3U39WCfJzZJcO7tJaO85XtWsufpqJA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiE9av--Ij2AhXS16QKHVWfCYYQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22pe%C3%A7a%20de%20que%20consta%22&f=false)); as duas metades da vagem do feijão, ervilha, e coisas desse tipo em vagens e cápsulas de frutos e sementes ([Cândido de Figueiredo 1899](https://books.google.pt/books?id=OS9AAAAAYAAJ&q=%22uma%20das%20pe%C3%A7as%20de%20certos%22&dq=%22uma%20das%20pe%C3%A7as%20de%20certos%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjkkJ2v_Ij2AhUJyKQKHUmeAzAQ6AF6BAgEEAI)); e mais uns outras aceções altamente especializadas (ver [Infopédia ― termos médicos](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/termos-medicos/valva)). Por sua vez, ***válvula*** ficou reservado para membranas ou peças que regulam o fluxo de líquido ou gás, deixando-o passar apenas num sentido. Primeiro, a propósito da circulação do sangue ([Raphael Bluteau 1721](https://books.google.pt/books?id=LytPUU4IhO4C&pg=PA358&lpg=PA358&dq=%22valvula%20termo%20anatomico%22&source=bl&ots=5Su9lwYI67&sig=ACfU3U1jhW8hqnuZWm9eJRYg3kXaLmSOsw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwilgcav15H2AhX_gc4BHVxgBx0Q6AF6BAgEEAM#v=onepage&q=%22valvula%20termo%20anatomico%22&f=false)), mais tarde também na mecânica ([Moraes Silva 1858](https://books.google.pt/books?id=lTBxS8oISF4C&pg=PA964&dq=%22duas%20pe%C3%A7as%20da%20porta%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjw86imgon2AhURzhoKHQ-2BBkQ6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22duas%20pe%C3%A7as%20da%20porta%22&f=false)).

Mas a partir dos anos 50 começaram a aparecer na literatura médica brasileira alguns *valva* em vez do tradicional *válvula*, e nos anos 90 *valva* já era até o termo mais comum; e em 2001 a Sociedade Brasileira de Anatomia adotou oficialmente o termo *valva* para cada uma das tradicionais *válvulas* do coração (ver [Aloir Queiroz de Araújo, “Valva ou válvula?”, *Arquivos Brasileiros de Cardiologia*, 2002](https://www.scielo.br/j/abc/a/mxr8sTT5yqVCWhDdQrwYGWq/?format=pdf&lang=pt)), o que já se reflete nos dicionários brasileiros. Em Portugal manteve-se a terminologia tradicional, que é a que aparece no [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/v%C3%A1lvula) e pormenorizadamente na [Infopédia ― termos médicos](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/termos-medicos/v%C3%A1lvula). De modo que baseado no [Aulete](https://aulete.com.br/valva) e no [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/v%C3%A1lvula/), temos no coração (com ligações à Wikipédia para quem estiver interessado em anatomia):

> **Termos tradicionais**                         **Novos termos**
> **e em uso em Portugal**                   **anatómicos no Brasil**
>
> [válvula mitral ou bicúspide](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%A1lvula_mitral)               valva atrioventricular esquerda
> [válvula tricúspide](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%A1lvula_tric%C3%BAspide)                              valva atrioventricular direita
> [válvula aórtica](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%A1lvula_tric%C3%BAspide)                                     valva aórtica
> [válvula pulmonar](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%A1lvula_pulmonar)                                      valva pulmonar

A evolução no Brasil reflete a da terminologia em latim. Pesquisei no Google Books, e encontram-se em obras de anatomia os termos latinos a par dos vernáculos. Antes de 1950 encontrei *valvula aortae* (literalmente ’válvula da aorta’) mas não *valva aortae*; este último só aparece, infrequentemente, nos anos 50; mas nos 70 já é dominante. Para isto terá contribuído a [*Nomina Anatomica* (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomina_Anatomica), uma terminologia em latim acordada internacionalmente. Na sua [primeira edição, 1895 (p. 68)](https://archive.org/details/dieanatomischeno00hisw/page/68/mode/2up?view=theater&q=Valvula%20tricuspidalis), encontramos apenas *valvula*; mas na [edição de 1961](https://books.google.pt/books?id=U7pqAAAAMAAJ&q=%22valva%20aortae%22&dq=%22valva%20aortae%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj5n7n365D2AhUfgv0HHQYpAuUQ6AF6BAgJEAI) (mas já aprovada em 1955 no 6º Congresso Internacional de Anatomistas) já vem *valva aortae* (*valvula* designa apenas compontentes da valva), tal como na sucessora da Nomina Anatomica, a [*Terminologia Anatomica* de 1998, ainda em vigor](https://fipat.library.dal.ca/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/FIPAT-TA2-Part-4.pdf) (para os interessados, fica o acesso à [*Terminologia*](https://sociedadeanatomica.pt/informacoes/terminologia/) completa).

A terminologia latina influenciou pelo mos três brasileiros: [Antônio Fortuna *et al*. (“Anatomia da valva atrioventricular esquerda”, *Revista Brasileira de Cirurgia Cardiovascular* 3(3), 1988)](https://www.scielo.br/j/rbccv/a/8rT5WNVbZ8PY4cQzGZ4KP7K/?format=pdf&lang=pt). Queixando-se eles das duplas e triplas terminologias, dizem:

> A nomenclatura recomendada pela Nomina Anatômica [5ª edição, 1984], constitui a alternativa para os que buscam a padronização da terminologia anatônica. De acordo com esta referência, utilizaremos, no presente trabalho, os termos “valva atrioventricular esquerda” [p. 203]
> […]
> Conclusões
> 1 O termo “valva atrioventricular esquerda” deve ser preferido ao “válvula mitral”. [p. 207]

Também a tradicional *válvula ileocecal* passou a *valva* no [Aulete](https://aulete.com.br/valva) e [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/v%C3%A1lvula/) (é uma prestimosa válvula/valva que impõe sentido único ao trânsito intestinal).

Este uso de *valva* no Brasil parece não ter ainda verdadeiramente passado para  fora do contexto médico. Procurei na [Hemeroteca Digital Brasileira](http://bndigital.bn.gov.br/hemeroteca-digital/), que tem o texto integral de imensos periódicos brasileiros, e encontrei *valva aórtica* só depois de 2010, e apenas três ocorrências; contra 19 de *válvula aórtica* no mesmo período. Isto vai de encontro à experiência do Schivile e Stafusa (ver pergunta e comentário acima).

Comment: O impacto da ditadura (1964 to 1985)  no Brasil teve muitas ramificações; uma delas foi o impacto no sistema educativo sobre várias gerações:  "Cardiologistas brasileiros começaram a usar valva para designar o que antes era válvula",  Credo, pensamos, em geral, que médicos são bem formados....eu sei, provar minha ideia aqui seria impossível. :)

Comment: Jacinto, muito obrigado pela resposta! Sabes dizer se esse uso de *valva* é exclusivo dos cardiologistas ou se é de todo médico?

Comment: @Schilive, o meu palpite é que poderá nem ser todos os cardiologistas. Certo é que na na imprensa da hemeroteca digital brasileira só encontro *valva aórtica* na década 2010-19, e só três ocorrências; contra umas 20 de *válvula aórtica*. Vou incluir uma nota sobre isso, quando tiver tempo...

Comment: @Lambie, este *valva* aparece em força já depois da ditadura. É possível que tenha sido influência do latim (há uma terminologia médica completa em latim internacionalmente acordada). O artigo que eu linkei sugere isso.

Comment: Eu dizia o oposto. Não influenciado pelo latim; pela falta de conhecimentos.

Comment: @Lambie, pois, eu não sei o que é que os médicos sabem nem como é as coisas se passam na profissão. Simplesmente me baseei no Aloir Araújo, que me parece fiável.

Comment: @Schilive, Fiz a tal atualização. Nós até temos um médico brasileiro aqui no site. Talvez ele nos possa dar mais esclarecimentos.

Comment: Jacinto, você não entendu o que eu disse. O rasgo semântico dos dois termos é a mesma coisa: regular o movimento de ar ou líquido ou gás em uma direção. Então não há razào para dois termos. "Federação Internacional das Associações de Anatomistas, que se reuniu pela última vez na cidade de São Paulo em agosto de 1997" = depois que o pessoal começou a usar o termo valva. Também pode ser a influencia do inglês.

Comment: @Schilive, descobri que a evolução do *valva - válvula* no Brasil mais ou menos acompanhou a evolução no latim. Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: @Lambie, na terminologia em latim já é *valva* desde os anos 50; não sei porque é que o Aloir destacou o congresso de 1997. Tive a atualizar com melhor informação, se quiseres ver.

Comment: Jacinto, será que o meu ponto não foi claro? Latim é uma coisa. Criar em português brasileiro outro termino não era necessário. Porque que os portugueses só tem um? Por causa do tipo de coisa que eu estou dizendo. Eu fiz um erro de português: queria dizer **traço semântico**. rasgo é español. Valva e válvula tem o mesmo traço semântico.

Comment: @Jacinto, interessante. Obrigado Jacinto pela resposta.

Comment: @Jacinto, evitei responder a essa pergunta justamente porque a padronização de termos médicos por aqui é quase caótica. Em um período de dez anos podem ocorrer até três ou quatro mudanças. Mas não é só no Brasil, isso também ocorre na América. Quando entrei para faculdade, havia uma patologia denominada "miocardiopatia hipertrófica",  cerca de 10 anos mais tarde, os presidentes das sociedades de cardiologia decidiram que o termo correto seria "cardiomiopatia hipertrófica".  Eu adotei o novo termo, acostumei-me a ele e, para minha surpresa, anos depois recomendou-se a volta ao termo anterior.

Comment: E isso acontece sempre na medicina.  Uma bactéria deixa de ser classificada como bactéria e passa a ser um fungo, o Dengue muda de gênero e passa a ser "a Dengue", e assim por diante.  O que é o termo correto hoje, já pode não ser amanhã.  O perônio passou a chamar-se fíbula já há muito tempo, a rótula passou a patela, o Campilobacter Pilori passou a ser o Helicobacter Pilori.  O esforço para acompanhar essas mudanças é quase diário.  A consequencia disso tudo é que ouvimos os colegams médicos dizerem valva quando queriam dizer válvula e vice versa.